# How to get all redis keys using crediscache

Tags: yii, redis, yii-extensions

I am using the cRedisCache extension of yii, how can I get all the keys of a pattern from redis  using cRedisCache.

Answer (score 3):

Suppost you are looking for all keys start from "ltp".

Add this code in main.php for redis configuration

```
cache => array(
    'class' => 'CRedisCache',
    'hostname' => '172.16.3.37',
    'port' => 6379,
    'database' => 0,
    'hashKey' => false,
    'keyPrefix' => '',
);
```

When using redis to get all keys

```
 $result =  Yii::app()->cache->executeCommand('keys', array('ltp_*'));

    foreach ($result as $mainkey => $value) {
        // your loop here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs at [the crediscache docs page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CRedisCache#executeCommand-detail) there is an `executeCommand`
Method which allows you to pass a Redis command. The Redis docs at http://Redis.io/commands detail the SCAN command which will let you iterate over some of the keys in the DB until you have gem all. This will not be a trivial task, but should work.